# Google calendar API updating all events instead of just selected event

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-calendar-api

My current problem is that I'm using google calendar API. When I attempt to patch an event the API updates all future events instead of just the selected event.

My project goes like this,
User selects date on calendar and then request is sent to backend to retrieve all events for that day.
Then the user can click on the event to confirm it and another request is sent to the server. During the request the calendar API should just update the event for the event clicked.

From the research I've done I think I must use recurrence and then the `EXDATE` but I tried to decipher the google calendar docs and didn't get anywhere...

This is the code I've tried so far.

```
    adjustEventForTeacher = async(userCalendarLocation, slotId) => {

        let getEventStartTime = await calendar.events.get({
           calendarId: 's',
            eventId: slotId
        })
        const getEventEndTime = getEventStartTime.data.end.dateTime
        getEventStartTime = getEventStartTime.data.start.dateTime
        console.log(getEventStartTime)
        const res = await calendar.events.patch({
            calendarId: 's',
            eventId: slotId,
            requestBody: {
                summary: 'Busy',
                name: 'Busy',
                status: 'confirmed',
                colorId: '0',
                // start: {
                //     dateTime: getEventStartTime
                // },
                // end: {
                //     dateTime: getEventEndTime
                // }
                // recurrence: [ `EXDATE;VALUE=DATE:${getEventStartTime}` ],
            }
            })

        console.log(res.data)
    }
```

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I see that even if I check the events in the future they all have same ID, might have to go for different approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not too clear in the documentation but I figured out how to change a single instance of a recurring event by analyzing how the events look like in the API after being changed in the UI.

As you've already noticed, using `update` or `patch` changes all instances of a recurring event. It makes sense since recurring events still only have a single ID and their recurrence is defined by their `recurrence[]` rules. That way the calendar doesn't have to create a potentially infinite amount of new events when they're set to occur daily without limit.

The trick is that instead you have to use the [`events.insert`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert) method to create a new event, while also specifying that it's a modification of an existing recurring event. This is done by adding the `recurringEventId` and `originalStartTime` fields in your request body. The `recurringEventId` should be the ID of the recurring event that you want to change, and the `originalStartTime` should have the `startTime` and `timeZone` of the specific instance that you want to change.

**Full explanation:** Here's a sample of a recurring event in the API, which you can find by creating one in the UI and using [`events.list`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list) to retrieve it. The actual output is longer but I trimmed down some of the irrelevant fields:

```
  {
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "id": "<original-recurrent-event>",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "created": "2022-10-28T02:58:32.000Z",
   "updated": "2022-10-28T02:58:32.287Z",
   "summary": "Recurrent event",
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2022-10-27T21:30:00-06:00",
    "timeZone": "your-timezone"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2022-10-27T22:30:00-06:00",
    "timeZone": "your-timezone"
   },
   "recurrence": [
    "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY"
   ],
   "eventType": "default"
  }
```

The above shows a daily recurrent event. The only difference between it and other events is that it has a `recurrence` rule. I replaced the actual ID with the `<original-recurrent-event>` placeholder.

When I made a change to this event in the UI for only a single day a new event was added which looked like this:

```
{
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "id": "<original-recurrent-event>_20221029T033000Z",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "created": "2022-10-28T02:58:32.000Z",
   "updated": "2022-10-28T02:59:30.474Z",
   "summary": "Modified event",
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2022-10-28T21:00:00-06:00",
    "timeZone": "your-timezone"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2022-10-28T22:00:00-06:00",
    "timeZone": "your-timezone"
   },
   "recurringEventId": "<original-recurrent-event>",
   "originalStartTime": {
    "dateTime": "2022-10-28T21:30:00-06:00",
    "timeZone": "your-timezone"
   },
   },
   "eventType": "default"
  }
```

This looks pretty much like a regular new event with a few differences:

- Its `id` is not randomly generated as usual. Instead it consists of the original event ID and adds a timestamp with the original start time in UTC.
- It has the fields `recurringEventId` and `originalStartTime` which I mentioned earlier.

With all that said, in practice you just need to insert a new event with those fields which would look something like this for you:

```
    const res = await calendar.events.insert({ // use insert method
        calendarId: 's',
        requestBody: {
            summary: 'Busy',
            name: 'Busy',
            start: {
                dateTime: getEventStartTime
            },
            end: {
                dateTime: getEventEndTime
            },
            recurringEventId:slotId,
            originalStartTime:{
                startTime:getOriginalStartTime,
                timeZone:getTimezone
            }
        }
        })
```

I don't have a Node environment to run this myself but I hope it gives you an idea of how to do it. When I tried it in the APIs Explorer in the documentation pages it worked as described. Strangely the documentation doesn't explain these fields so I submitted some feedback in hope that they can clarify this for the future.

##### Sources:

- [events.insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert)
- [events.list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list)

Comment: You sir are a legend... I was up all night and still couldn't get it working... was playing around with RRrule and EXDATE... thank you again so much, if I could give you all my 93 reputation I would.

Comment: Also to clarify for anyone who got confused like me, when it says originalStartTime that is where the date of the event you want changed not the first date where the event was created. Lets say the first event is ```01/01/2000``` and then you have it recurring every day. Lets say you want to change the third day you would do ```03/01/2000``` in the originalStartTime.

Comment: After using google calendar for another week I found this... ```singleEvents boolean Whether to expand recurring events into instances and only return single one-off events and instances of recurring events, but not the underlying recurring events themselves. Optional. The default is False.```

Comment: Adding the code above enables you to make recurringEvents have individual ids, allowing you to edit them directly.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an event with recurrence rule, it creates a recurring event with an id, let's call it `<recurrent_event_id>`. If you use this id in update or patch, it will update all recurrences. To update a single event, you need to use the instance id of that event.

You can use the '[instances](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/instances)' endpoint of the Calendar API to retrieve the instances of a recurring event.
`https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendarId}/events/{eventId}/instances`

It will return `items[]` property where you can find ids of each event basically looks like `<recurrent_event_id>_20230601T120000`.

When you use the instance id of the event that you want to edit in the [patch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/patch) call, it will update the single event.